# new lines and spaces added to querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, query-string

I am experiencing a rather strange problem on the page I am working on.
This is an address I am working on:

> `http://localhost:49726/Redirect.aspx?ACTION=FLIGHTHOTEL`

now in Page_Init for the Redirect.aspx I am accessing `Request.QueryString.ToString()`, I am getting a value like that:

```
%0d%0a++++++++&ACTION=FLIGHTHOTEL
```

Where are the extra spaces (+) and newlines/tabs (%0d%0a) coming from?
To confirm `Request.RawUrl` does not contain these extra spaces, while `Request.Url` does:

> `http://localhost:49726/Webpages/Redirect.aspx?\r\n_______&ACTION=FLIGHTHOTEL`

(I replaced spaces with `_` for the purpose of visibility)

Is there an easy way to not have them there? I am not keen on substring as I am not sure how and if this is static or random...

Thanks.

--- EDIT ---

Haha, funny thing. I have looked in my web.config and found lines that catch url and redirect to another even before any page is loaded, like so:

```
  <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>~/redirect.aspx?([^\/]*)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>~/Webpages/Redirect.aspx?$1</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

Now this particular line had some extra new lines and spaces, like so:

```
<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>~/redirect.aspx?([^\/]*)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>
        ~/Webpages/Redirect.aspx?$1
                             </SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

This was causing the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It is Working fine for me.
May be there will be some problem with your server.

```
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

I just used this
  But if i set spaces like u said I am getting `%5cr%5cn++++++&ACTION=FLIGHTHOTEL`

Comment: Hmm the question would then be... what settings on the server could cause a behaviour like that? First time I came accross something like that, and I have used Request.QueryString many times before...